# Why my Http Proxy doesn't reply [SYN,ACK] after received a [SYN] packet from the client?

Tags: linux, tcp

I have a http proxy running on Linux (RHEL 5.5), intermittently it doesn't reply [SYN,ACK] packet after received a [SYN] packet from the client. This issue can be recovered by restarting the proxy. I ran the gstack against the proxy process, however the stack of each thread doesn't indicate any problems(hanging). And there were less than 100 connections staying at the "SYN_RECV" state during this issue.

Any ideas? For such issue, where should i start to debug?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Lack of SYN,ACK usually indicates that the server software doesn't `accept` the connection. This might be due to a number of reasons, most likely exhaustion of resources of some kind or another. You could try to `strace` the server process to see whether it is in the `accept` syscall, or equivalently doing some `select` or `poll` with the server socket among the file descriptors to select from.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a firewall issue. If a TCP connection on receiving the first SYN + ACK response, it's most likely your packet wasn't sent to the proxy server.

Check on both server side and client side.